# RecyclerView swipe action without deletion

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture, itemtouchhelper

I want a RecyclerView with swipe gesture to trigger a action like mark the swiped item as favorit.
It is possible to use the ItemTouchHelper but disable the view deletion after swipe?
A common pattern is a swipe to display some button but this is not the wanted behavior.

Comment: Yes it is possible. But questions this broad are not likely to receive good/helpful answers. Do you have a specific programming problem (complete with MCVE) we can help with?

Comment: I need the Java Code how to extend the ItemTouchHelper callback to block the complete swipe out of the screen and trigger the swipe callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implement a solution which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/felixWackernagel/11f1abdefcc5d1add940dde422a4baec). Thanks to Xenofon how helped me.